# Determining if interval of convergence is possible for a given power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Given the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n (x-1)^n$, is it possible for it to have an interval of convergence of $(-3,5]$?

My first though is yes, if it has a radius of convergence of 4, it is possible for it to have the interval. But I do not know how to prove that it is possible for one end to be excluded and one endpoint to be included.

Comment: $\sum x^n/n$ is a simple example. It converges for $x=-1$ but not for $x=1$.

Comment: To explain Martin's example a little further, the interval of convergence is $x \in [-1,1)$, because $x = 1$ gives you the harmonic series, which diverges, but $x = -1$ gives the alternating harmonic series, which conditionally converges to $\ln 2.$ (this is actually a pretty good hint by the way: think about absolute and conditional convergence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it converges at $x=5$, the radius of convergence is at least  $4$, with convergence on $|x-1|=4$ being up in the air.

For instance,  adjusting the hint in the comments a little,  consider  $\sum_{n\ge1}\dfrac {(\dfrac {x-1}4)^n}{(-1)^nn} $.